# Integration by parts for fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, fractional-calculus, rough-path-theory

I have encountered a problem in a paper called Volatility is rough by Jim Gatheral et al.

A stationary fractional Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process ($X_t$) is
defined as the stationary solution of the stochastic differential
equation
$$dX_t = \nu dW^H_t− \alpha (X_t − m)dt$$
where $m ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $\nu$ and $\alpha$ are positive parameters (see Cheridito et al. 2003). As for usual Ornstein–Uhlenbeck processes,
there is an explicit form for the solution which is given
by
$$X_t = \nu \int^t_{−\infty}e^{−\alpha (t−s)}dW^H_t+ m  \qquad \quad (3.3) $$
Here, the stochastic integral with respect to fBm is simply a
pathwise Riemann–Stieltjes integral, see again Cheridito et al.
(2003).

Proposition 3.1 Let $W_H$ be a fBm and $X^\alpha$ defined by (3.3)
for a given $\alpha > 0$. As \alpha tends to zero,
$$E\left[\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|X^\alpha_t− X^\alpha_0− \nu W^H_t|\right]\to 0$$

Then the proof goes like this:

Starting from equation (3.3) and applying integration by parts, we get
$$X^\alpha_t = \nu W^H_t −\int_t^{−\infty}\nu \alpha e^{−\alpha(t−s)}W^H_s ds + m$$

and some proofs that I know; it is just this part that I don't understand.

So my question is: How do I even perform integration by parts for the fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in this proof. I don't see anyway how to obtain the answer by integration by parts. I'd appreciate if someone can answer or link me to somewhere that has methods/answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the Proposition A.1 in [link](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ejp/1464037576), they provide a more rigourous proof.

Essentially, we apply the integration by part to $(e^{\alpha t}W_t^H)$
\begin{equation}
d(e^{\alpha t}W_t^H) = \alpha e^{\alpha t}W_t^Hdt +e^{\alpha t}dW_t^H
\end{equation}
Then integrate
\begin{equation}
e^{\alpha t}W_t^H - e^{\alpha b}W_b^H = \int_b^t \alpha e^{\alpha s}W_s^Hds + \int_b^te^{\alpha s}dW_s^H\end{equation}
So we have : $\int_b^te^{\alpha s}dW_s^H = e^{\alpha t}W_t^H - e^{\alpha b}W_b^H - \int_b^t \alpha e^{\alpha s}W_s^Hds$. Replacing the latter in $(3.3)$ by taking $b\to-\infty$, you will find the answer.